# The resource "ResourceName" could not be resolved error in WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I'm seeing an error trying to use a custom converter in my WP8 app.

I defined my converter in a namespace: standrighthere.Utilities:

```
namespace standrighthere.Utilities
{
    public class NonNullVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value == null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I then included it in the App.xaml manifest as so:

```
<Application.Resources>  
    <utilities:NonNullVisibilityConverter x:Key="NonNullVisibiltyConverter" />  
</Application.Resources>
```

I then tried to use it in my phone application page like this:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Source={Binding User}, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=NonNullVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

However, it keeps giving the error:

`Error  1   The resource "NonNonNullVisibilityConverter" could not be resolved.`

I feel like I must be missing something really obvious here.

Comment: Might be a copy/paste error, but you called it "NonNullVisibiltyConverter" in the resources and "NonNonNullVisibilityConverter" in the binding

Comment: Don't put it in <ResourceDictionary> just remove those.

Comment: @KooKiz Ooops, its a copy paste error.

Comment: @TimHeuer I removed them and the error's still there.

Comment: Arrrggghhh!
I spelled it as NonNullVisibiltyConverter instead of NonNullVisibilityConverter (missing an "i")

Comment: @chustar well... that's what I said :D

Comment: @KooKiz turn it into an aswer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo. You called your converter "NonNullVisibiltyConverter" in the resources and NonNonNullVisibil***i***tyConverter in the binding.